# Paging in CSOM with sharePoint results

Tags: client-object-model

how do we implement paging for results after we get results in onSuccess function, I have like this:

```
            for(var i = 0; i <results.length; i++){
                                 }
```

But this way, it will loop through all documents, but how do I implement paging, and loop through only items I want, like 5 document each time.

Comment: This [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx) might help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i learned about it by the link provided by nitish.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx